# Python multiply list of lists element-wise

Tags: python, list, numpy

What is the neatest way to multiply element-wise a list of lists of numbers?

E.g.

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]

-> [6,24,60]
```

Comment: In your given example, the product of any 3 elements of the same index in the 3 different sublists is equal to taking the product of the whole sublist of the same index. Just pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `np.prod`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
>>> np.prod(a,axis=1)
array([ 6, 24, 60])
```

Comment: this assumes that all sub-lists have same size.

Comment: @François If he is using numpy to start with this is a valid assumption.

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'np', I can only guess np is for Numpy?

Comment: @ThorSummoner Yes, `import numpy as np` is the canonical way of importing numpy.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension and `reduce`:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> lis = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
>>> [reduce(mul, x) for x in lis]
[6, 24, 60]
```

Comment: argh! you beat me to it (+1). Ok, I'll add another one, with `functools.partial` and `map`

Comment: I recommend `reduce(mul, x, 1)` so that it extends safely to empty lists (the empty product is, by definition, equal to 1).

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
import functools
answer = [functools.reduce(operator.mul, subl) for subl in L]
```

Or, if you prefer map:

```
answer = map(functools.partial(functools.reduce, operator.mul), L)  # listify as required
```